# Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments, but question has 1

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

In my app,user can write their question and admin can replay their question's answer.It's sucessfully add the id document in database But i get this error.
I am using firebase firestore database

here is my code
QuestionAddActivity.kt

```
class QuestionAddActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var mAuth: FirebaseAuth
private lateinit var db: FirebaseFirestore
private lateinit var storageReference: StorageReference
private lateinit var resultUri: Uri
private val admin: String = "DHIsHa2tUNMjv9DWrjdEuJIG0vP2"

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_question_add)

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference

    if (mAuth.currentUser.uid == admin){
        answer_edit_text.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }else if(mAuth.currentUser.uid != admin){
        answer_edit_text.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
    }


    question_image.setOnClickListener {
        CropImage.activity()
            .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
            .setMinCropResultSize(512, 512)
            .setAspectRatio(1, 1)
            .start(this);
    }

    submit_btn.setOnClickListener {
        val question: String = question_edit_text.text.toString().trim()
        val answer: String = answer_edit_text.text.toString().trim()
        addQuestion(question, answer)
    }
}

private fun addQuestion(question: String, answer: String) {
    val userId: String = mAuth.currentUser.uid
    progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    val time = System.currentTimeMillis()

    val questionData = QuestionData(question, answer, userId, time)
    db.collection("question").add(questionData).addOnCompleteListener {task ->
        if (task.isSuccessful){
            progressBar.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            val intent = Intent(this,QuestionActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            Log.d("question", "$task")
        }else{
            progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
    }
   }
```

AnswerActivity.kt

```
class AnswerActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var mAuth: FirebaseAuth
private lateinit var db: FirebaseFirestore
private lateinit var dbupdate: DocumentReference
private lateinit var storageReference: StorageReference
private lateinit var q: String
private lateinit var a: String
private val question:QuestionData = QuestionData()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_answer)
    val bundle:Bundle? = intent.extras
    q = bundle!!.getString("question").toString()
    question_answer_edit_text.text = Editable.Factory.getInstance().newEditable(q)
    a = bundle!!.getString("answer").toString()
    answer_answer_edit_text.text = Editable.Factory.getInstance().newEditable(a)

    db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    var questionId: String = question.id.toString().replace("/","_")

    answer_btn.setOnClickListener {
        val questionData = QuestionData(q, a, question.userId, question.time)
        db.collection("question").document(questionId).set(questionData)
            .addOnCompleteListener{
                if (it.isSuccessful) {
                    Log.d("Answer", "${it.result}")
                }else{
                    Log.d("error", "${it.exception}")
                }
            }
    }
}
```

QuestionActivity.kt

```
class QuestionActivity : AppCompatActivity(),OnClickListener {

private lateinit var mAuth: FirebaseAuth
private lateinit var db: FirebaseFirestore
private val questionAdapter by lazy { QuestionAdapter(this) }

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_question)

    db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    val questionList = ArrayList<QuestionData>()

    question_details_btn.setOnClickListener {
        val i = Intent(this,QuestionAddActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(i)
    }

    db.collection("question").addSnapshotListener{ querySnapshot: QuerySnapshot?, firebaseFirestoreException: FirebaseFirestoreException? ->

        if (querySnapshot != null) {
            for (doc:DocumentChange in querySnapshot.documentChanges){
                val questionData:QuestionData = doc.document.toObject(QuestionData::class.java)
                questionData.id = doc.document.id
                questionList.add(questionData)
                questionAdapter.setData(questionList)
            }

        }
    }
    setUpQuestion()

}

private fun setUpQuestion() {
    question_recyclerview.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this,
        LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false)
    question_recyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true)
    question_recyclerview.adapter = questionAdapter
}

override fun onClick(item: QuestionData, position: Int) {
    val intent = Intent(this,AnswerActivity::class.java)
    intent.putExtra("question",item.question)
    intent.putExtra("answer",item.answer)
    startActivity(intent)
    Toast.makeText(this,"$position",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    Log.d("clicked","$position")
}
 }
```

QuestionData.kt

```
data class QuestionData(
    val question: String? = null,
    val answer: String? = null,
    val userId: String? = null,
    val time: Long = 0L
 ){
    @Exclude
    var id: String = ""
  }
```

And my database is
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSy1M.png

here is my error log
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8jmO.png

How can i solve this error? Thank you

Comment: What is the value of "questionId" inside `db.collection("question").document(questionId).set(questionData)`?

Comment: add the log and in which file/line you are having erroneous code

Comment: I inherit questionId from question:QuestionData = QuestionData() object @Alex Mamo

Comment: @Kamal Nayan please see my question, i added logcat error.I hope you understand

Comment: I was not asking from which class you inherit, rather the value of "questionId" inside db.collection("question").document(questionId).set(questionData).

Comment: @Alex Mamo I check the firebase ,it's created the field but this field's value is empty

Comment: I believe the issue here is that you are creating your `question` variable as an empty `QuestionData` object, and it's where you later get the `questionId` value from, which will also be empty, by then you are passing an invalid value in this query `db.collection("question").document(questionId)`, can you check if that is the case?logging the mentioned values will confirm this.